# Why can't an object have an array position associated with it instead of using a hashmap?

Tags: hashmap

I am trying to understand Hashmap concepts. I understand that it can be useful to find a certain object by hashing an object to find its location in memory.

However, why can't we have a property of an object correspond to its position in memory, so we could refer to that when searching for an object. As for insertion, we could have a counter store the number of objects, so that insertion could be O(1).

Why isn't this feasible?

Comment: So, what you're saying is that I need to have a reference to an object so that I can get the property that lets me know the position in memory so that I can get a reference to the object?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding hashmaps. Usually, if we were to search for a City, we would use its name property of a city object, right? Then we would hash its name to find the object. I am wondering if instead we use a _position_ property, which would then tell where the city object resides, and then we could access other values.

Comment: If you have a *position* property then you must already have an instance of the object. There would be no need to then need to look up the object as you already have it.

Comment: Isn't some sort of key needed for searching an object in a HashMap? Don't we have that key, but not the instance?

Comment: Yes, but it's pointless putting that key in a property on the object. You need to know how to get the key without having the object in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that it can be useful to find a certain object by hashing an object to find its location in memory.

Hashing does not do that!  What it does is to compute a number from the *value* of the object.  Even in the case where `Object::hashCode` is not overridden, the code is still not the object's address in memory.

One problem with addresses (and why they can't be used) is that an object's address **changes** when the GC moves it.  So each time the GC ran you would need to rebuild all of the hash tables.  Identity hashcodes don't have this problem / cost.  An object's identity hashcode never changes.

A second problem is that if you used addresses (only) as the hashcodes, you wouldn't be able to handle the (more common) case of hashing based on the *value* of the key.

Comment: I didn't mean that it translates directly to the object's address, but rather a value would be hashed into something that would in some way lead to the full object.

Comment: There is no known *practical* algorithm that will generate an id that maps uniquely to an object reference, without using something like a `HashMap` under the hood to implement the mapping.  (But if you can find or invent such an algorithm ... )